# jar libraries not updated in eclipse with git

Tags: java, eclipse, git

I am developing java projects in eclipse and version controlling with git.

What I found today was that the jars of user library was not being updated after pulling a project from git server to another repository/directory. The newly exported jars after adding new classes or functions were not recognized.

So I removed the user library with the problematic jars. The eclipse java project still has access to the jars.

1. Create a dir.
2. Git init
3. Create an empty java project
4. Pull from git server

The above is the steps that caused this problem. I didnt commit the empty project before pulling.

Thanks~

Comment: What dependency methodology what you use in your project: Maven, Gradle or add JAR files to classpath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried refreshing the project? (Right click on your project and then select `Refresh`)

Your changes done to the file system (pulling stuff from git) are not known to to Eclipse, so you have to explicitly tell Eclipse that it has to refresh its idea of what are on the file system.

Comment: Eclipse has git support in a plugin that most likely is included, so it might be useful to use that to update the file system to avoid having to tell Eclipse explicitly.